# bell curves mean,median, modes, standard deviation

Tags: self-study, normal-distribution

Which of the bell curves in the histogram has the highest mean, median, mode & standard deviation? [image]

Comment: You need to add the self-study tag.

Comment: Visually they all seem to have approximately the same mean, median and mode

Comment: 1. Please [merge](https://stats.stackexchange.com/help/merging-accounts) your accounts ([account 1](https://stats.stackexchange.com/users/237906/lewis-tonks) and [account 2](https://stats.stackexchange.com/users/237913/lewis-tonks)).  2. Please don't post essentially the same question twice. If there's some problem with the first question, edit rather than repost.

Answer (score 2):

The first thing to do is to break down the problem into its four constituent parts.  The question is really four questions.

Which of these images has the greatest mean?

Which of these images has the greatest median?

Which of these images has the greatest mode?

Which of these images has the greatest standard deviation?

Greek letters are usually used as the notation for parameters.  It is common practice to denote the population mean with $\mu$ and the population standard deviation with $\sigma$.

Since there are three graphs, let us notate them as $\mu_1,\mu_2,\text{ and }\mu_3$.  We will make the tallest graph, usually called the densest graph, $f_1$ with a mean of $\mu_1$ and a standard deviation of $\sigma_1$.  The second tallest will be $f_2$ leaving $f_3$ for the flattest or least dense graph.

The question can then be broken down into is $\mu_1>\mu_2$, is $\mu_2>\mu_3$ and is $\mu_1>\mu_3$.  Ask yourself where the mean is supposed to be at if this is a normal distribution.  Is one mean greater than another one in this graphic?

For the questions on the median and the mode, answer the question as to the relationship between the median and the mode in the normal distribution.  How are the mean, median, and mode linked to each other for the normal distribution?

They have different linkages with different distributions, what is the link for the normal distribution?

For the standard deviation, it may help again to think what a standard deviation is.  It is the measure of how spread out data *should* be from the mean.  How far from the center are the data likely to go?

Unfortunately, the phrase standard deviation is a two-word descriptor.  It doesn't tell you what makes it standard or from what it deviates.

The standard deviation is a one-dimensional measurement, but a two-dimensional example might help here.

If you think of the mean like the very center of a dartboard, then if each ring is of equal width, then each ring is one standard deviation from the mean.  It is standardized to be of equal width.  An example of a non-standard deviation would be tree rings.  They surround the center point, but some are wide and some are narrow.  Real data is irregular.  The standard deviation helps create a standard width.

At some point, some king decided how long an inch was.  That became the base of all standard measures in the English system of measurement.  Statisticians decided that they needed a standard width however astronomy data and microbiology data are not even at the same scale, so they decided to let the data itself determine the scale.  The standard deviation could be thought of as how wide one unit is.  It is the inch from the center.

So a question of which picture has the greatest standard deviation is which one will *normally* deviate from the center the greatest.  Since all three functions run from $-\infty$ to $\infty$ they are equally wide, but they do not have equal standard deviations.  The question should be which function tends to throw things the greatest distance from the mean because the lines represent the relative probability of seeing that exact location being a result.  For which function is it most normal to see something far from the center?